# Java Glassfish java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.sun.jna.Pointer on glassfish 3.1.2.2

Tags: java, jar, glassfish, dependencies, jna

I have serious problem and I have tried all possible ideas, I did read also answers on stackoverflow on similar issue whaich were of no use to me.

What actually happens is I am deploying application on `glassfish 3.1.2.2`. I am using 2 jars: `jna.jar` and `platform.jar` (I tried different versions, last I tried was actually: `jna-3.3.0.jar` and `jna-3.0.0-platform.jar`) what I am trying to is to read Windows registry keys. I am also calling other methods from jna.jar (interesting I don't have to include jna.jar in my lib directory inside my ".ear" file, what indicates - it must be allready present somewhere on glassfish. When I searched for it on glassfish directories - I couldn't find it.). Anyways - when I call methods of jna.jar - it is working just fine, when I call methods of platform.jar, first of all I have to deploy that platform.jar in lib directory of my .ear file, secondly - it never works - because I get: ...

**java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.sun.jna.Pointer.(J)V from class com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinReg$HKEY**

I have tried anything I could have think of: rebuilding my workspace, renaming jars, including both of them in lib folder of .ear file, including one of them, not including at all, including those jars in `glassfish3\glassfish\domains\target\lib\ext`, including one or the other in `glassfish3\glassfish\domains\target\lib\ext`, trying different versions of those 2 jars, nothing worked. I tried using jni4j.jar instead of jna.jar and platform.jar, still didn't help.

**Here is actual code, using jna.jar and platform.jar:**

```
    if (Advapi32Util.registryKeyExists(WinReg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\CitySyncSafety")) {
        path = Advapi32Util.registryGetStringValue(WinReg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\CitySyncSafety", "Path") + File.separator + "DetectEngine";
        logger.warning("POJO path is: " + path);
    } else {
        path = "";
        logger.warning("Else POJO path is: " + path);
    }
    String libPath = System.getProperty("java.library.path");
    if (path != null && !path.equalsIgnoreCase("") && !libPath.contains(path)) {
        logger.warning("Library paths are: " + libPath);
        System.setProperty("java.library.path", System.getProperty("java.library.path") + File.pathSeparator + path);
    }
    if (path != null) {
        //System.loadLibrary(path + File.separator + "cutilityProj1.dll");
    }
```

It causes that illegal access exception spoken of. When I try to use jni4j.jar with the following code, I do not get any exception, because I do not get anything at all:

```
    try {
        Reg reg = new Reg("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE");
        Reg.Key cp = reg.get("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE");
        Reg.Key sound = cp.getChild("CitySyncSafety");
        String p = sound.get("Path");
        path = p  + File.separator + "DetectEngine";;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        if (path == null) {
            path = "";
        }
    }
```

It just hangs forever on the first line. Please note I have ensured that appropriate key and directories do exist, so we can exclude this issue. I will appreciate any help, as I spent already 2 days on this single issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution :). I can't tell if all the steps are necessary (I mean, I could but I can't be bothered now, while at work). All it takes is to combine jna.jar and platform.jar into 1 jar and place it in glassfish3\glassfish\domains\target\lib and in glassfish3\glassfish\domains\target\lib\ext (actually I bet it is enough to place it in glassfish3\glassfish\domains\target\lib, but I didn't test it).

Well, at least now it works!

Please vote it up, if it helps you.